# How to first filter the dataframe and then match with the same dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. df1 & df2. I want to filter df2 based on the values of df1 and then count the frequency of values and compare with df1 again.

Example:

df1:

```
Project_Number
S100
S100
S200
S300
S300
S300
S400
S400
```

df2:

```
Project_Number
S100
S200
S200
S300
S300
S300
S500
```

Now first filter the df2 based on the values of df1. Keep only those values which is present in df1 also.

df2_new:

```
Project_Number
S100
S200
S200
S300
S300
S300
```

Now take the frequency of both the dataframes-

```
df1['Count'] = df1['Project_Number'].map(df1['Project_Number'].value_counts())
df2_new['Count'] = df2_new['Project_Number'].map(df2_new['Project_Number'].value_counts())

df1-                              df2_new
Project_Number  Count             Project_Number   Count
S100            2                 S100             1
S200            1                 S200             2
S300            3                 S300             3
S400            2
```

Now take the difference between above 2 dataframes and print the result-

```
df_difference-

Project_Number  
S100           
S200
S400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filtering, then compare `Series` from [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for not equal and convert sorted index to one column `DataFrame`:

```
df2_new = df2.loc[df2["Project_Number"].isin(df1["Project_Number"]),'Project_Number']

s1 = df1['Project_Number'].value_counts()
s2 = df2_new.value_counts()

df_difference = s1[s1.ne(s2)].sort_index().index.to_frame(name='Project_Number',index=False)
print (df_difference)
  Project_Number
0           S100
1           S200
2           S400
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter, try using `isin`

```
df2_new = df2[df2["Project_Number"].isin(df1["Project_Number"].unique().tolist())]
```